# Why is my app not showing in the list of default launchers?

Tags: android, launcher

I have an application where it is going to be the home screen, default launcher. I am implementing this by using the CATEGORY_LAUNCHER in my intent and CATEGORY_HOME in my manifest file, the home activity has ACTION_MAIN and CATEGORY_HOME. Because there are multiple homes set then android prompts the user to select one with the optional extra of selecting a default one. There are many default apps in this list on my emulator but my app is not one of them. Does someone know how to get my app onto the list?

Here is how I am sending the intent:

```
Intent startMain = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
startMain.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
startMain.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(startMain);
```

Here the relevant part of the manifest:

```
<activity
        android:name=".NewHome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: i think you're supposed to have the DEFAULT category as well

Comment: Sorry, i accidentally left it out, still dosnt work with it

Comment: Sorry again! I am such a fool!! Yes that was the problem!!! MY bad everyone!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to show your application in Default  launchers. Change your code as:

```
<activity
        android:name=".NewHome"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />  
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Thankyou, and I will accept it when I am aloud :) sorry about the confusion!